# Help me normalize my simple book catalog schema

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, plsql, normalization

This is a simple database model for an online library catalog. I am trying to normalize it, if possible. What do you think I should change or do differently?

For example, I am not sure about the table authors. It has only one column "name" which is also a primary key and I use it also as a foreign key in another table. Is that a good practice? Also should I put two columns there ("first_name" and "last_name") instead of just one?

```
CREATE TABLE books (
    isbn VARCHAR2(13) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR2(200),
    summary VARCHAR2(2000),
    date_published DATE,
    page_count NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE authors (
    name VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE books_authors_xref (
    author_name VARCHAR2(200),
    book_isbn VARCHAR2(13),
    CONSTRAINT pk_books_authors_xref PRIMARY KEY (author_name, book_isbn),
    CONSTRAINT fk_books_authors_xref1 FOREIGN KEY (author_name) REFERENCES authors (name),
    CONSTRAINT fk_books_authors_xref2 FOREIGN KEY (book_isbn) REFERENCES books (isbn)
);

CREATE TABLE book_copies (
    barcode_id VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    book_isbn VARCHAR2(13),
    CONSTRAINT fk_book_copies FOREIGN KEY (book_isbn) REFERENCES books (isbn)
);
```

Comment: just a suggestion - you don't need a NOT NULL constraint on a column declared as PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's reasonably normalized.  I'd add a numeric "author_id" to the authors table and use that instead of author_name in the books_authors_xref table and use that for the relationships, which lets you do things like deal with two authors with the same name, and change how you store the name later without making a mess.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think all four tables are in 5NF. What do *you* think?

But . . .

Author names aren't unique. Adding an ID number to the authors table identifies the row, but it doesn't identify the author.  For example, assume there are two authors with the name "Richard Knop". You can't enter both into your existing table, because there's a primary key constraint on author names. If you try to fix that by adding an ID number, you might end up with this.

```
author_id    author_name
--
1            Knop, Richard
2            Knop, Richard
```

Which one of those is you? How do you know?

Comment: But how to solve that problem? There are actually cases where two literature authors from different countries have the same name! It's rare but it happens. Maybe I should also add the date of birth there?

Comment: You should add whatever you use to distinguish yourself from that other guy.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using an "author_id" as mentioned by Christo and Catcall, you might also consider using a "book"id" for the primary key on your book table. Not all things published/printed have an ISBN-- either because the book predates ISBN or it was printed by someone that didn't think it needed an ISBN (such as a lot of the training material that I've seen over the years).

Comment: At one of my local libraries, you can check out toys, maps, DVDs, CDs, recorded books, posters, sheet music, magazines, newspapers, paintings, and--wait for it--tutors! Oh, and you can check out books, too.

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it simply works... I make little bit change and table is created. Moreover,
ISBN is used as foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE book_copies
( barcode_id VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ISBN VARCHAR2(13),
CONSTRAINT FK_BOOK_COPIES FOREIGN KEY (ISBN )REFERENCES books (isbn))
```